# How can I use sharedPreferences Date Diaplay sent next Activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need to send data `Date Display` to next `Activity` and keep that data

```
private void updateDisplay()
{      
SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ShowdatanameActivity.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();

   mDateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear).append(" "));   
   editor.putString("key1", mDateDisplay);
   editor.commit();
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(ShowdatanameActivity.this,Showdata_result_resume.class);
   startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: you can't get data in another activity or what?

Comment: no  i dont know how to use for date

Answer (score 0):

Well that's true you can acces to Data/Calendar object from every place of your application. But if you insist:

You've put your string to SharedPreferences under "key1" so in other activity you have to call:

```
SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences("KEY_FOR_YOUR_DATA",ShowdatanameActivity.this);
String data = app_preferences.getString("key1","");
```

### So when you call SharedPreferences you also need key for them. It's some kind of "database version", you can write anything there (i use for example PREFS-KEYv1, and when I need new one I'm incrementing to v2). And don't use same key everywhere it's bad practice.

The other method you could use to send your String to other activity is via intent.

```
intent.putExtra("key1",yourStringVariable);
```

and Showdata_result_resume in onCreate after setContent you can get it by:

```
String data = intent.getExtras().getString("key1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using code like this to make preferences code portable between various apps and classes.

from a fragment I get the sharedpref like this.  Notice how I have the preferences named in a resource and I use getActivity to get to the preferences.

```
    sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.preferences), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

From the main activity I get the sharedpref like this.  Notice how I have the preferences named in a resource.

```
sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preferences),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

the resource which is shared by all classes in the app.

```
<string name="preferences">com.gosylvester.hilbilyfashliegt.prefrences</string> 
<string name="about_firstrun">com.gosylvester.hilbilyfashliegt.firstrunabout</string>
```

now to get the data from any class I referer to it with an R string resource.

```
_Checked = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.about_firstrun),
            false);
```

Good Luck